# Alloy and Alloy*

Tags: alloy

I have read the paper about Alloy* last week and it seemed very interesting to me and the fact of integrating higher-order quantifiers will help me with my work. But I want to know is it is still an on going project and if I could keep on working on there version of the Alloy Analyser UI and is it stable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Alloy* project is currently not under active development.  It is, however, stable, and other researchers are using it to carry out their own research.

You can get it (including sources) from http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/hola/.

Feel free to contact me directly if you need further help with compiling/using it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer !! I have received your answer to my email as well !!

Answer (score 1):

In the mean time ... Alloy (not Alloy*) is now an open source project on Github: https://github.com/AlloyTools We are discussing also including Alloy*